# devexpress xtracharts showing date only

Tags: c#, datetime, charts, devexpress

I have created a devexpress chart (v13.2) which has datetime in x-axis and values in Y-axis.

Currently in x axis it shows date like this:
[image]

but i need to show date and time also by default like this:
[image]

Even though the x-axis is coded to fetch datetime from database but still it shows date only not the time.
Why?

Comment: could you provide x- Argument and y- Value data to know the exact issue. how are you modifying the x axis values(means fetching)

Comment: @NiranjanKala currently my main concern is how to show datetime in x-axis coz currently x-axis is showing date but without time for which I used XYDiagram d =(XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram as XYDiagram; d.AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General; as per reply by DmitryG in answer section but I am getting null reference error

Comment: Null reference, which section of code.

Comment: You are not setting which Y axis will indicate value of which series.. have you missed or setting some where else??

Comment: @NiranjanKala: well its working now I defined diagram before chartControl1.datasource=datatable so thats y it was giving error.. and yes i did not write the y-axis part wait i will introduce it too in above code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's two step process show date and time in the scale:

1. Set the [Axis.DateTimeOptions.Format](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsAxisBase_DateTimeOptionstopic) property to [DateTimeFormat.General](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsDateTimeFormatEnumtopi).
2. Then Axis.DateTimeScaleOptions property with custom settings.

   ```
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General;
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignment = 
                                   DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeGridAlignment.Minute;
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit = 
                                     DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasureUnit.Minute;
   ```

Check the below code and configuration for the chart which make me to get the desired results as you want to accomplish:

Form.cs :

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // This line of code is generated by Data Source Configuration Wizard
    chartDataTableAdapter1.Fill(dbDataSet1.ChartData);
}
```

Designer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
    DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram xyDiagram1 = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram();
    DevExpress.XtraCharts.PointSeriesLabel pointSeriesLabel1 = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.PointSeriesLabel();
    DevExpress.XtraCharts.PointOptions pointOptions1 = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.PointOptions();
    DevExpress.XtraCharts.LineSeriesView lineSeriesView1 = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.LineSeriesView();
    this.chartControl1 = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl();
    this.chartDataTableAdapter1 = new ChartTest.DBDataSetTableAdapters.ChartDataTableAdapter();
    this.bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
    this.dbDataSet1 = new ChartTest.DBDataSet();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chartControl1)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(xyDiagram1)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pointSeriesLabel1)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(lineSeriesView1)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).BeginInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dbDataSet1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // chartControl1
    // 
    this.chartControl1.DataAdapter = this.chartDataTableAdapter1;
    this.chartControl1.DataSource = this.bindingSource1;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignment = DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeGridAlignment.Minute;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit = DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasureUnit.Minute;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions.Format = DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeFormat.General;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.Range.AlwaysShowZeroLevel = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.Range.ScrollingRange.SideMarginsEnabled = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.Range.SideMarginsEnabled = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisX.VisibleInPanesSerializable = "-1";
    xyDiagram1.AxisY.Range.AlwaysShowZeroLevel = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisY.Range.ScrollingRange.SideMarginsEnabled = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisY.Range.SideMarginsEnabled = true;
    xyDiagram1.AxisY.VisibleInPanesSerializable = "-1";
    this.chartControl1.Diagram = xyDiagram1;
    this.chartControl1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
    this.chartControl1.Legend.Visible = false;
    this.chartControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
    this.chartControl1.Name = "chartControl1";
    this.chartControl1.SeriesDataMember = "VariableName";
    this.chartControl1.SeriesSerializable = new DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series[0];
    this.chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentDataMember = "LastTime";
    this.chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentScaleType = DevExpress.XtraCharts.ScaleType.DateTime;
    pointSeriesLabel1.LineVisible = true;
    pointOptions1.ArgumentDateTimeOptions.Format = DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeFormat.General;
    pointSeriesLabel1.PointOptions = pointOptions1;
    this.chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.Label = pointSeriesLabel1;
    this.chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ValueDataMembersSerializable = "LastValue";
    this.chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.View = lineSeriesView1;
    this.chartControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.chartControl1.TabIndex = 0;
    // 
    // chartDataTableAdapter1
    // 
    this.chartDataTableAdapter1.ClearBeforeFill = true;
    // 
    // bindingSource1
    // 
    this.bindingSource1.DataMember = "ChartData";
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = this.dbDataSet1;
    this.bindingSource1.Sort = "";
    // 
    // dbDataSet1
    // 
    this.dbDataSet1.DataSetName = "DBDataSet";
    this.dbDataSet1.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
    this.Controls.Add(this.chartControl1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(xyDiagram1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(pointSeriesLabel1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(lineSeriesView1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chartControl1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dbDataSet1)).EndInit();
    this.ResumeLayout(false);

}

#endregion

private DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl chartControl1;
private DBDataSetTableAdapters.ChartDataTableAdapter chartDataTableAdapter1;
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
private DBDataSet dbDataSet1;
```

Chart data:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Axis.DateTimeOptions](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsAxisBase_DateTimeOptionstopic) property and set an appropriate [DateTimeFormat](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsDateTimeFormatEnumtopic) value:

```
((XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General;
```