# how to set limits for datetime in xtracharts devexpress

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress

I am using a devexpress xtrachart in which in x-axis there is date.
Now,
the date in x-axis I am binding from database as:
y-axis has values

```
chartControl1.DataSource=dt;//used datatable
chartControl1.SeriesDataMember = "VariableName";
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ArgumentDataMember = "LastTime";
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "LastValue" });
chartControl1.SeriesTemplate.ChangeView(ViewType.Line);
((DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram)(chartControl1.Diagram)).AxisX.Label.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General;
```

Now, the datetime in database is for today date and different hours like

[image]

but in chart its showing like below only one datetime:
[image]

How can i fix this, I just want it to show today's datetime(and time not as 00:00:00) 
That is if for today range in x-axis must be like:
startdate in x-axis one hour before current datetime and enddate in x-axis one hour after current datetime
or one hour difference

example if current datetime is 2014-10-11 10:00:00
in x-axis it show like 
2014-10-11 09:00:00 , 2014-10-11 10:00:00 , 2014-10-11 11:00:00 ..

I tried VisualRange and WholeRange too but its not working.

Comment: which version of dlls are you using. Visual Range and WholeRange are introduced separately in version 14.x. if you are using 13.x then WholeRange and ScrollRange are exist.

Comment: my version is 13.2.8.. in 13.2.8 VisualRange also present but I don't think these work for datetime. do they?

Comment: surely work.. you just need to customize the Range property to just display 24 hours only.. you just need to specify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's two step process show date and time in the scale:

1. Set the [Axis.DateTimeOptions.Format](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsAxisBase_DateTimeOptionstopic) property to [DateTimeFormat.General](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsDateTimeFormatEnumtopi).
2. Then Axis.DateTimeScaleOptions property with custom settings.

   ```
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeOptions.Format = DateTimeFormat.General;
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignment = 
                                   DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeGridAlignment.Minute;
   (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.MeasureUnit = 
                                     DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeMeasureUnit.Minute;
   ```

Currently Axis.DataTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignment and MeaureUnit property by default set to Day, so you are able to see the single data data with Aggregation operation(Sum etc).

Refer:
[devexpress xtracharts showing date only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336117/devexpress-xtracharts-showing-date-only/26362527#26362527)

> I just want it to show today's datetime(and time not as 00:00:00)
>   That is if for today range in x-axis must be like: startdate in x-axis
>   one hour before current datetime and enddate in x-axis one hour after
>   current date time or one hour difference

Try to tweak with Range properties, below is the just example snippet:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Today;
XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)chartEditor.Diagram;

diagram.AxisX.WholeRange.Auto = false;
diagram.AxisX.VisualRange.SetMinMaxValues(start.AddHours(0), start.AddHours(24));
```

Comment: i am getting error in (XYDiagram)chartControl1.Diagram).AxisX.DateTimeScaleOptions.GridAlignment =                                DevExpress.XtraCharts.DateTimeGridAlignment.Minute; as The GridAlignment property must be greater than or equal to the current measure unit.

Comment: It worked.. actually I was implementing these in Demo but in actual code the DevExpress version is 13.1 in which WholeRange and VisualRange Not available so I used   ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram)(chartControl1.Diagram)).AxisX.Range.MinValue = StartDate.AddHours(-1);
                ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram)(chartControl1.Diagram)).AxisX.Range.MaxValue = StartDate.AddHours(1); but its not taking datetime format any way to fix this..

Comment: well wait for while.. i shall get back with you a demo code snippet soon.. you can use chart wizard to know the affects of property changes.. just try in design mode till then.

Comment: i fixed it myself : ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram)(chartControl1.Diagram)).AxisX.Range.Auto = false;
                ((DevExpress.XtraCharts.XYDiagram)(chartControl1.Diagram)).AxisX.Range.SetMinMaxValues(Min, Max); where min max are dates i.e., from min to max

Comment: it is exactly same what that the example code snippet intended to do.. it set the min and max limit of the range in 13.1 rather than using the WholeRange. .WholeRange = Range in 13.1